# Select certain tags to display instead of all tags in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress I am display all the tags by using this function

```
<?php 
$tags = get_tags();
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
$tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

$html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
$html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
?>
```

This then prints out all the tags.

Instead of display all tags is there a way I can say which tags I wish for it to display the slug and link to?

I have also tried this

```
<?php 
$tags = query_posts('tag=html');
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
$tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

$html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
$html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
?>
```

I am sure the answer is on this page but I can not come up with the solution http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this solution might not be much more maintainable than just linking them manually, but you could do something like...

```
<?php
$tags = query_posts('tag=html');
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';

$wanted_tags = array ( "aSlugThatIWant", "AnotherSlugThatIWant" );

foreach ( $tags as $tag )
{
    if (in_array($tag->slug, $wanted_tags))
    {
        $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
        $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
        $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
    }
}

$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
?>
```

Edit: Just fixed a mistake.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. No output in the div, just an empty div. I am trying to use something like http://www.smashingmagazine.com/tag/photoshop/ as you can see each tag has its own page and certain tags are printed like the ones on the left hand side.

Comment: Did you use the slug in the array? Use the tag slug.